# What are the differences between fish shell and bash when handling named pipes?

Tags: bash, named-pipes, fish

When executing these command in fish shell

```
$ mkfifo answer
$ nc -vv -l -k -p 8001 <answer | tee -a answer
```

The command hangs.
If I write to `answer` through `echo "" > answer`. Then the `nc` resumes and starts listening correctly.
If, in contrary I `CTRL-C` the hanging process, here is the message:

```
^C<W> fish: An error occurred while redirecting file 'answer'
open: Interrupted system call
```

On the other hand, in bash, when executing:

```sh
$ mkfifo answer
$ nc -vv -l -k -p 8001 <answer | tee -a answer
Listening on localhost 8001
```

The command **doesn't** hang and start listening directly.

What happens differently in fish and in bash that explains this different behavior?

Comment: In addition to the answer by ridiculousfish I'll point out that you can't actually depend on the bash behavior; or any other POSIX shell AFAICT. Opening a FIFO for reading will block until a process opens it for writing. That `<answer` open blocks in bash but isn't obvious to you because it happens in a child process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key difference is that fish opens redirected files before `fork` in the parent shell, while bash does it after `fork`, in the child process.

When you open a named pipe for read, the open call will block until there is a corresponding writer (and vice versa). Your pipeline contains both reader and writer, but requires that the corresponding open calls occur in parallel, in the child processes. In fish `nc` cannot start until the file is open, so you get a deadlock.

One workaround is to arrange for a child process to open the file on its own, instead of using a redirection. For example this will avoid the deadlock:

```
cat answer | nc -vv -k -l -p 8001  | tee -a answer
```

fish behaves this way because it also uses threads, which limits what you can do in a forked child.